# Ho to use JNDI to connect to oracle database in tomcat server

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jndi

If using mysql, I can easily connect to my java web project using jndi.  But how to connect oracle 11g database to my java web project? Can it be done using the same method?

Comment: trial and error so far give me this error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: your data source informations are not valid please check the tag and add  the config of JNDI file to the question

Comment: huhu, manage to link for the first time. i change the localhost name to the database name/sid. then next error, table or view is not exist, i add (pop) to the sql script: select name, email from pop.test

Comment: that means you did not create that table in data base .. your question is incomplete and invalid please add your  config so that people can see

Comment: Hi @BOSS, i'm sorry for the incomplete information in the question, and thank you for your attention. I believe I have managed to solved the problem already...:) Thanks again.

Comment: The steps to set up a JNDI DataSource for Oracle is no different then for MySQL. You only need to supply a different JDBC URL and driver class (and probably username and password as well).